# Django paging with slicing

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and Python and I'm trying to understand how to accomplish paging without getting all the records from a QuerySet first.  All the examples I've seen with QuerySets will get all the records first like below.

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(site=site.id)    
paginator = Paginator(tickets, settings.PAGE_SIZE)
```

This seems to make sense so that the Paginator will have a reference to how many pages it needs.  However, this seems inefficient to get all the records for each page request.  I know that QuerySets can be sliced to return a range of records.

How do I design my paging in order to only get the records pertinent for that page (slicing?), yet still have paging features?

**Edit:** Added template code that iterates.

```
  {% for ticket in tickets.object_list %}
        {{ ticket }}<br/>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlying queries for the `QuerySet` objects are not executed until you explicitly evaluate them. Explicit evaluation occurs whenever you iterate through them, which includes calling `str()` or `unicode()`.

Thus, the above code snippet is indeed efficient. The line `tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(site=site.id)` creates a new `QuerySet`, but the query isn't evaluated yet.

For the same reason, stuff like `Model.objects.filter(foo).filter(bar).order_by(baz)...` doesn't execute a single SQL query.

Comment: For reference, refer to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated for the execution timing of the querysets.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I modified my question to include the for loop in the template.  Are you saying that it's not querying SQL until it actually performs the for loop?  If so - then I don't understand how the paginator knows how many pages there are.

Comment: @Steve Suh - If you have a queryset object, which is what Ticket.objects.filter(...) returns, you can call queryset.count() separately, and it will issue a separate COUNT(*) query. This is what the pagination is doing.

Comment: Mike is right. Paginator calls count() method of the queryset to get the size.